# The position of 'been' and 'he' in the following question.

Tags: questions, word-order, style, formal-language

When writing a question that has **two** auxiliaries, which of these is grammatically correct?

> Could not **he have been**  sick that day?
>
> Could not **have he been** sick that day?

Also in **formal/academic** writing, would it be **'could not'?** Or can I used **couldn't** in formal writing? The combination of 'could + not + have + been' sounds like such a mouthful to me.

Comment: *Could not* contracts before inversion if at all: *He could not → He couldn't → Couldn't he* but *He could not → Could he not*, and not *\*Could not he*, which is generally ungrammatical, though it's possible for this form to appear in formal language, albeit quite rarely, due to Heavy NP Shift.

Comment: And *could not have he* is impossible. In questions the subject inverts only with the **first** auxiliary, not with any subsequent complement of that auxiliary.

Answer (score 1):

"*Could not*" can almost always be contracted to "*couldn't*" even in formal writing. Usually they are only separated to emphasise the *not* or if you were attempting to sound archaic.

Therefore I would suggest that

> Couldn't he have been sick that day?

is the best way to phrase that question.

Plus, here is some info on the Present Perfect: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfectcontinuous.html

Answer (score 0):

> Could not he have been sick that day?
>
> Could not have he been sick that day?

They're both incorrect. You could say any of these:

*Could he not have been sick that day?*

*Couldn't he have been sick that day?*

*Is it not possible that he was sick that day*?

*Isn't it possible that he was sick that day?*

The versions with contractions are definitely less formal. If you're trying to be formal, I would avoid them. Yes, they're a mouthful -- but then again, you're not speaking them, so they're only a penful or a keyboardful.